# Prove that the sequence $(-1)^n (-n)^2/(9n^2)$ does not converge to a specific number

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

Prove that $\{(-1)^n  (-n)^2/(9n^2)\}$ does not converge to $\frac{1}{9}$ or $\frac{-1}{9}$, I've already chosen an epsilon whats the next step. DO NOT SOLVE ALL THE WAY! Do I chose an $N$?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't get to choose an $N$. The negation of "$x_n\to a$" is: there is $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $N$ there is $n>N$ for which $|x_n-a|\ge \epsilon$. This means:

1. you get to choose $\epsilon$
2. you have no control on $N$
3. you have to come up with $n$ such that $n>N$ and $|x_n-a|\ge \epsilon$.

It seems that one of $n=N+1$ and $n=N+2$ ought to work, if your choice of $\epsilon$ was good.

Comment: So basically for which ever n i choose this can never be true

Comment: This is not what I said. I meant that one of the numbers $N+1$ and $N+2$ is even while the other is odd. If you are proving the sequence does not converge to $1/9$, you take $n$ that is odd, which will make $x_n=-1/9$. If you are proving the sequence does not converge to $-1/9$, you'll want $n$ to be even.

Comment: Actually i revise this you prove the negation of the statement true there by proving it does not converge to this point.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(-1)^{(-n)^2}}{9n^2}=\frac{(-1)^{n^2}}{9n^2}\to 0\text{ if }n\to\infty $$
Moreover, the limit is unique, indeed, if a sequence $(x_n)$ converge to $\ell$ and $\ell'$, then if $\varepsilon>0$,
$$|\ell-\ell'|\leq|x_n-\ell|+|x_n-\ell'|<\varepsilon$$
if $n>N$ for some $N\in\mathbb N$, and so $\ell=\ell'$, what terminate the proof.

Comment: So because the uniqueness of limit theorem I can choose the distance between them to be as small as i want it?

Comment: Yes, but with $0$ only, not with $\frac{1}{9}$ or $\frac{-1}{9}$.

Comment: I think my professor wants us to prove that it does not converge to specific numbers with out using the fact that it simply does not converge. So with using the negation of the convergence definition we show that it does not converge for an epsilon that i choose.